# How to update existing public key on instances in Oracle?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I just started working for a client which uses Oracle Cloud with 100+ servers. However my problem is that I need to replace the public key existing in the *authorized_keys* file in an automated fashion.
The servers are segregated in groups of 10 and all of these have their own compartment. I have tried to look at solutions such as their API, Ansible or Terraform to help me solve this problem, but I haven't found any.

Comment: There isn't any API to do it in any Cloud Vendors (I guess) because it will be a insecure solution. To update key on any system, be it Cloud or OnPrem, it requires access to the system (authN) along with right permissions to do so (authZ). Ideal solution will be to ssh on all the computes and update the keys or use Chef. OCI also provides one interface to 'Run Command' on Computes using it's Cloud Agent but to update keys you need to add the user of this Agent to sudoers for granting Admin privileges. Refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/runningcommands.htm)